# Can Jenkins use all .jtl-files (JMeter) in a specified folder?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I want my Jenkins to use all .jtl files in a specified directory to be used for the Jenkins-JMeter-plugin.
Is it possible to use a placeholder or something like that to configure my Jenkins that way?

Thanks in advance!

...
To be more specific with more details:
My problem is - I want to generify the overall-process. I don't want to make changes in the configuration of my jenkins-server when I use another testplan or something like that. Also I cannot specify a general name, because the number of testplans I want to use may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I can specify it using a placeholder via *.jtl and my problem wasn't a problem. I'm sorry for asking that needless question...

If someone is interested, the jenkins-configuration works as following:

```
echo "Report capacity tests"
perfReport 'test/target/jmeter  /results/*.jtl'
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically have 2 options:

1. Use [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) which picks up all the .jmx files from `<Project Dir>/src/test/jmeter` folder
2. Use [Taurus tool](http://gettaurus.org/) which naturally "understands" JMeter .jmx test scripts and can execute them either sequentially or in parallel, see [Taurus - Working with Multiple JMeter Tests](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/taurus-working-multiple-jmeter-tests) for details.

There is also possibility to use [foreach loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop) in [Windows Command Prompt](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) or in [Bash shell](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/), however Maven or Taurus would be much easier to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm using JMeter Maven Plugin and I know that I can pick up all the .jmx-files from a folder, but I'm not sure how this fixes my problem to configure my Jenkins to use all .jtl files (the results) in a folder... Maybe I did not provide enough information for you to make my problem clear or I don't get your answer right...